# How to replace characters with wild card in Libreoffice?

Tags: replace, find, wildcard, libreoffice

I am working on data from different water sources.

Here's what the data looks like:

```
Station Code    Water Quality                    
1001           "WATER QUALITY OF RIVER- A"      
1002           "WATER QUALITY OF RIVER- B"
```

There's data on several rivers. I want to replace every  "WATER QUALITY OF RIVER- A" with just label "RIVER".

Find & Replace with Wildcard "WATER QUALITY OF RIVER- *" to "RIVER" only makes it "RIVERA" not just RIVER which I want.

I want to further split and analyze it using R language so I need to change the names.

Answer (score 1):

You got the regular expression wrong, try:

`WATER QUALITY OF RIVER- .*`

WFM  [LO5.2/Linux]